# Adding User In Active Directory gives Error Directory Object not found powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi every one i am using the following code to add user to active directory but i am getting the error
Directory object not found

```
$NewUser = Read-Host "New Username"
$firstname = Read-Host "First Name"
$Lastname = Read-Host "Last Name"
$NewName = "$firstname $lastname"


New-ADUser -SamAccountName $NewUser -Name $NewName -GivenName $firstname -Surname   
$lastname -Path "ou=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -AccountPassword (Read-Host "New Password"   
-AsSecureString)
```

Comment: where it says ou=Users,,,,,,, is it right of it should be CN=Users  if i right CN=Users script runs fine but i cannot see any user created

Comment: i would like to see the user to get created on the main Users OU screen in Active directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you didn't really look at the `Get-Help New-ADUser -Full` since it specifies (please note the second bullet point):

> ```
> -Path <string>
>     Specifies the X.500 path of the Organizational Unit (OU) or container where the new object 
>     is created.  
>
>     In many cases, a default value will be used for the Path parameter if no value is 
>     specified.  The rules for determining the default value are given below.  Note that rules 
>     listed first are evaluated first and once a default value can be determined, no further 
>     rules will be evaluated.
>
>     In AD DS environments, a default value for Path will be set in the following cases:
>       - If the cmdlet is run from an Active Directory PowerShell provider drive, the parameter 
>     is set to the current path of the provider drive.
>       - If the cmdlet has a default path, this will be used.  For example: in New-ADUser, the 
>     Path parameter would default to the Users container.
>       -  If none of the previous cases apply, the default value of Path will be set to the 
>     default partition or naming context of the target domain.
> ```

So it should default to your Users OU and you don't really need to specify that. Also, I think you want -DisplayName and not -Name in the context that you are using it, and probably -Name and not -SamAccountName for that context. Try this:

```
New-ADUser -Name $NewUser -DisplayName $NewName -GivenName $firstname -Surname $lastname -AccountPassword (Read-Host "New Password" -AsSecureString)
```

Keep in mind that this account will be created as disabled by default. Add `-Enabled $true` to your command to have it create an enabled account. This does require a valid password be supplied. The account will still be created if the password is not valid, but it won't have a password, and will not be enabled.

Comment: just a quick question with this script what can i use so that i will have predefined password and not ask user to enter pass ....New-ADUser -SamAccountName $NewUser -Name $NewName -GivenName $firstname -Surname $lastname -displayname  $Newname -Path "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -AccountPassword (Read-Host "New Password" -AsSecureString) -Enabled $true

Comment: `Get-Help ConvertTo-SecureString -Full` should show you what you need to do what you want with the password.